# Mock require/import modules using cypress

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocking, sequelize.js, cypress

I'm using sequelize with graphql to connect my postgresql in my react nodejs project. And I'm using Cypress for unit testing. While doing that, I got stuck on how to mock the module import.

```
describe('db config using sequelize', { tags: ['@unit'] }, () => {
  before(() => {
    const SequelizeStub = {
      authenticate: new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => { resolve(true) }),
      DataTypes: cy.stub().returns({}),
    }
    cy.stub('sequelize').returns(SequelizeStub)
  })

  it('db config authenticate', async () => {
    const { connect } = require('@db/common/dbconfig')
    assert.isBoolean(connect.authenticate())
  })
})
```

The `@db/common/dbconfig` file calls the `require('sequelize')` and creating the object for sequelize and using the Sequelize object I'm connecting to Postgresql.

So while writing the unit test case coverage for dbconfig file, I would like to mock the `require('sequelize')` itself instead of the module gets loaded for testing.

So I wrote a stub and replacing it with `'sequelize'` assuming that it will mock. But not sure this is the right approach. While running it, I'm getting the following error.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

> Because this error occurred during a `before all` hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: `db config using sequelize`

> Although you have test retries enabled, we do not retry tests when `before all` or `after all` hooks fail

Can someone help me with this stub mocking?

Comment: How did you mock `sequelize` now?

Comment: That's where I was not sure. My assumption was, when I do `require('sequelize')` inside dbconfig.js, the stub I have created here will be returned instead of actual node module.

Answer (score 0):

Learnt that without importing the actual model, it is not possible to mock it.

So I updated the code as follows,

```
  const SEQUELIZE_NAMESPACE = {
    Sequelize: require('sequelize'),
  }

  const mSequalize = {
    authenticate: cy.stub().callsFake(
      (params, callback) => {
        return new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => resolve())
      }),
    define: cy.stub().callsFake(
      (params, callback) => {
        return {}
      }),
  }
  cy.stub(SEQUELIZE_NAMESPACE, 'Sequelize').callsFake((params, callback) => mSequalize)
```

Used the same const `SEQUELIZE_NAMESPACE` in source file as well as follows,

```
  const SEQUELIZE_NAMESPACE = {
    Sequelize: require('sequelize'),
  }
```

And then created object as follows,

```
const sequelize = new SEQUELIZE_NAMESPACE.Sequelize(...)
```

and then it worked. Thanks for one of my peer (@rsmuthu) who helped me fix this.